# Android - Open session not working with last Facebook app version

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the last SDK of facebook to publish an image with some text, and until yesterday it's fine, did work like I thought with or without Facebook application installed on device. But I updated the Facebook application, and now it doesn't working with new version of Facebook app. What I'm doing wrong?

This is my code to open current session:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if(session == null || session.isClosed()){
                //session = new Session(activity);
                session = new Session.Builder(activity).setApplicationId(ConstantsSoccerWay.FACEBOOK_API_KEY).build();
                Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);
                openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
                openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                session.openForPublish(openRequest);
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                posting = true;
            }
```

When session it's opening, it's show up an popup asking user if he want allow my application to publish on him wall, but when he press the OK button, on callback "onSessionStateChange" my session still closed.

Someone can help me?

PS: I added publish_actions permission

Comment: I believe you can't just do openForPublish if you don't have "basic" permissions first. Try doing an openForRead with an empty permission set, and then do a requestNewPublishPermissions with publish_actions after the initial open succeeds.

Comment: Yes your right, I actually come here to answer my own question. I figure it out that the last Facebook version forces me that I ask for basic_info permissions too, even if I don't need it, but without app installed, that permissions it's not needed. But thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ming Li said, it's mandatory (with Facebook app installed) that I ask for basic_info permissions before I ask for publish permissions. This request have to be done separately, and on the order I said (first Read for basic_info and then for publish).